# Access error opening a video through absolute url on IIS

Tags: html, asp.net, iis

I need a absolute url for my video player that i am using. When i try to access the video it gives me following error
while url is 'http://mywebsite.com/w/videos/vid.mp4'

> 404 - File or directory not found. The resource you are looking for
>   might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily
>   unavailable.

I have tried it by shortening the url 'http://mywebsite.com/w/videos/'

> 403 - Forbidden: Access is denied. You do not have permission to view
>   this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

Same way when i try to access a image it opens up. no access error here
http://mywebsite.com/w/img/logo.png

I am a front end developer - i have created html pages with javascript/jquery. The server on which i am placing the files have Asp.net hosting (other website on the server is in asp.net). I have tried many helps but all are vain. I will be grateful if someone help me out. If i am not clear do let me please.

Thanks

Comment: It sounds to me as if there is a directory called w\videos. But obviously, the server disallows to list files in directories. But there seems not to be a file called vid.mp4. You should check if the file name is correct and the file is correctly uploaded to the web server.

Comment: i thoroughly checked no issue with the path but server is not allowing to access as described above.

Comment: I have found to pages which might help you: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248033 & http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943891. (They say that IIS also returns 404 if the MIME type (`video/mp4` in your case) is restricted. You might have to contact your site's provider on this issue.)

Comment: @stubT thanks this help me a lot in understanding of errors...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just added the extension `.mp4` in `MIME type (Multipurpose Internet Mail Extensions)` in IIS. By defualt this extension was missnig. Just by adding extension fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your hosting--->>virtual directory---->>MIME Type -->>

add your video extension after adding your access video.